# Is my Java hello-world program correct?

Tags: java, parameters, return-value

I just started a Java Programming class and received my first assignment. I am tasked with the following

1. Construct a simple flowchart that describes simple logic flow through a program (this is easy, I have done this)
2. Translate said flowchart into pseudo code (I know this is easy, but still working on it.)
3. Create a simple module based off that pseudo code, which accepts a parameter and returns a value.

"Technically" speaking, is the Hello World! initial program doing what #3 is requesting? I suppose I am just a little confused on terminology as to what a "parameter" is and what a "value" is in Java.

Does anyone have an example they could point me to? Or is this the same as saying something like

```
Mymethods test1 = new MyMethods();
int aVal = test1.total();
System.out.println("Method result = " + aVal);
```

(pulled this from the book)

Just slightly confused. Any help to explain this to my like I'm 5 would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is...

Comment: Do u mean line no. 3 ?

Comment: I tried to edit this question's title to get *some* information into it, but I'm not sure I got your meaning correctly...

Comment: By hello world i guess he meant hello world like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int myMethod(int a, int b)
{
   int value = a+b;
    return value;
}
```

**Code Details**

In the above example a and b are parameters, and v is value...

anything that is returned is called value.
anything that is passed (e.g. a and b) is called parameter.
**Your book example**

```
Mymethods test1 = new MyMethods();
int aVal = test1.total();
System.outprintln("Method result = " + aVal);
```

**Explanation**
in line 3 "Method result =" +aVal" is the parameter and printed output will b the value :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is what I was looking for. Being a visual learner, and having our textbook (written by a programmer) assume we already know basic coding, it makes it tough. Our text does not go over any basics, just here is examples of code, here are some definitions, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is what parameters are first see this :
what functions are ?<\b>
If I say you

> Raise your hand !

That could be said as `you.raiseHand()`

If I say you

> Raise your hand by 120°

It could be `you.raiseHand(120)`

Now that 120 is the value that is passed as argumemt.

How values go?<\b>

Consider this function

```
public boolean raiseHand(int deg){
useEnergy(10);
if(canRaise(deg))return true;
return false; }
```

Your passed 120 goes as deg.

Your program:

```
Mymethods test1 = new MyMethods();
int aVal = test1.total();
```

System.out.println("Method result = " + aVal);

In line 1 you are creating an instance (object) of class `Mymethods`. Its like you are creating a substance that has access to Mymethods. Rather read more about class. I guess it wasnt a good eg.

In line 2 you are creating a new variable and storing result of function call. As first eg of raising hand you are storing if you have succesfully raised hand or not.

In last you are printing it

Answer (score 0):

it says you should accept a parameter and return a value. That means that your method should accept a parameter for example:

```
public int addTen(int initialValue){
     return initialValue+10;
}
```